# How to set a class method equal to multiple functions? - Javascript

Tags: javascript

How would one do something like the following:

```
var turret = new Turret();  
Turret.prototype.fire = shootMissiles("atAirUnits"),
shootMachineGun("atInfantry"), 
setReload();

turret.fire();
```

I want know how to make it so that a call to `turret.fire();` calls all of these functions with their given parameters. Keep in mind the `setReload` function needs to still have access to `this.reloadTime` from the Turret class. I understand function composition to a certain extent, but with that the result of one of the functions is passed as an argument to the next which I do not want.
**Further Explanation** Any of these functions such as shootMissiles could take different or more arguments, such as "atTanks" or "atRandom". Also any other class such as rocketSoldier could use shootMissiles function in its fire function with different parameters. Another function such as shootMissiles might need access to Turret class variables such as this.missileSize. *If I have been unclear, please comment with how I should elaborate.*

Comment: Write a function that calls those things in that order?

Comment: These functions are used like puzzle pieces. Some classes might not have rockets, or reload, but they have a machine gun. so I would have to write a new function for each new combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
Turret.prototype.fire = function () {
    shootMissiles("atAirUnits");
    shootMachineGun("atInfantry"); 
    setReload();
};
```

Comment: These functions (shootMissiles, shootMachineGun) are not methods of the class Turret, they are global. Does this matter?

Comment: In testing out your answer I am finding that the functions cannot access  Turret's variables by calling this.variable. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: You have to pass the reference of the turret (`this`) as parameter to the functions.

Comment: Example: `shootMissiles("atAirUnits", this)`

Comment: Thanks. I figured, but now things are starting to look messy. Well I guess beggars(coders) cannot be choosers.